# What's the point of using a BUILD_GENERAL1_2XLARGE in CodeBuild if it takes 8 minutes to provision?

Tags: aws-codebuild

We use CodeBuild and most projects use BUILD_GENERAL1_LARGE.  I am trying to make a project build faster (it takes about 4 minutes now).  I switched it to BUILD_GENERAL1_2XLARGE and it took 10 minutes because it took 8 minutes to provision, even under subsequent runs, it was similar.

So, what's the point of using a BUILD_GENERAL1_2XLARGE in CodeBuild if it takes 8 minutes to provision?